# Irreducible real cubic polynomial in 2 variables, 4 possibilities for what variety looks like.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[x, y]$ be an irreducible cubic polynomial. Consider the affine variety$$V = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x, y) = 0\}.$$Find four qualitatively different possibilities for what $V$ looks like. Prove this is all one can get.

Thoughts on the problem so far: each of the four comes from a polynomial of the form $f(x, y) = y^2 - g(x)$, where $g$ has degree $3$. But I do not not know what to do from here on out. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Qualitatively different" is not a mathematical notion.

Either way, if $V$ is defined over reals, it contains some real points since we can always fix one real variable so that we get a cubic equation over reals in the other variable which always has a real solution.

Any irreducible plane cubic having a rational point (i.e. a real point in this case) can be "transferred" to the Weierstrass normal form, see *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, §1.3 by Silverman and Tate. More precisely, they are birationally equivalent both considered as projective curves.

In fact, in characteristic $0$ ($\neq 2$, $3$) the Weierstrass normal form can be written as $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$.

If $4a^3 + 27b^2 \neq 0$, the cubic is smooth and equation $x^3 + ax + b$ has either one or three real roots. We can sketch the graphs of $y^2 = x(x^2 + 1)$ and $y^2 = x(x^2  - 1)$ as such examples.

[image]

If $4a^3 + 27b^2 = 0$, the cubic has a singular point (it can have at most one). There are two cases: either $x^2 + ax + b$ has a real root with multiplicity $3$ or a real root with multiplicity $2$ and a simple root.

In the former case $a = b = 0$ and we have an [ordinary cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)#Examples) $y^2 = x^3$ at the origin. In the latter case we get a [node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety#Nodes) which after translation of the $x$-coordinate gets $y^2 = x^2(x+1)$.

[image]

If OP and I are thinking the same thing, there are no other possibilities how $V$ might "look" like (but this is rather a viewpoint of differential geometry).